# ios 8 Add Hoc Distribution

Tags: php, ios, iphone, ios8

Does iOS 8.x all support the OTA link over HTTPS ?

I want to download the app from url before being registered to istore.

I am trying ota distribution for ios 8. I have extracted .plist file from ipa file through php coding.

Does it possible to download the app before being registerd to the istore
for ios8

its showing warning

Warning:- This app is not set to this url ->itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://smashchart.com/scdev1/IPA-Distribution-master2/files/cConnects/cConnects.plist

My cConnects.plist file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://smashchart.com/scdev1/IPA-Distribution-master2/files/cConnects.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.htshc.cConnects</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.1.8</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>cConnects</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server doesn't support SSL (https). Replacing http links with https will not magically make it work.

Unfortunately OTA distribution only works over SSL (which is probably why you tried to replace your links with https). So you have to host your files on a server that supports https downloads like Google Drive or Dropbox.

Here is a way to do it with Google Drive :

- Host your ipa file on Google Drive and get a sharing url.
- Convert this sharing url into a download url (https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/)
- The url you get is actually an url that redirects to another url. It will work in a browser and it works under iOS 7 but often doesn't work under iOS 8, so you have to get the real url.
- Run the following curl command : `curl -v 'your_url'`. The `Location` header will contain the real download url. Add this url to your `.plist` file.
- Host your `.plist` file on Google Drive. Get the sharing url, then the redirect url and then the real download url the same way as before.
- Encode this url (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)
- Generate your link with this format : `itms-services://www.example.com?action=download-manifest&url=encoded_url` (`www.example.com` can be replaced by any valid domain, it's just there to make the link clickable).

You should be able to apply similar steps with other services. Always check that your download urls don't redirect to another url, it doesn't work well under iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

Your http server's ssl certificate does not configuration correct。
The https limit does not only add a "s" after the link's http prefix, you should config a ssl certificate on your server.
You can you some PaaS service like testflight or you can host your ipa and plist file on some CDN service provide for https visit permission.

Comment: It was really a headache thanks for your help now the app is downloading via ota....